# google chrome/windows 7 where to find those addresses that have been bookmarked

Tags: bookmarks

after using bookmark favorite-the star-where do I find the address that I have bookmarked? 
I have bookmarked a jigsaw puzzle sight that I wish to go to, but am not able to find where the address went after bookmarked. How do I find where it is?

Comment: Please mark an answer as solution.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your Bookmarks Bar isn't showing.

You can press CTRL+SHIFT+B to display the bookmarks bar or go to your Chrome Settings menu > Bookmarks > Show Bookmarks Bar

[image: Updated Bookmarks Bar Image]